# SQL ORACLE : Is it possible to convert NUMBER with CHAR (varchar2 datatype) to NUMBER datatype

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a big problem right now and I really need your help, because I can't find the right answer.
I am currently writing a script that triggers a migration process from a table with raw data (data we received from an excel file) to a new normalized schema.

My problem is that there is a column PRICE (varchar2 datatype) with a bunch of **traps**. For example: 540**S**, 25**oo** ,     **I**200 , **S**000 .

And I need to convert it to the correct NUMBER(9,2) format so I can get: **5405, 2500, 1200, 5000** as NUMBER for the previous examples and **INSERT INTO my_new_table**.

**Is there any way I can parse every CHAR of these strings that verify certain conditions?**
**Or others better way?**

Thank you :)!

Comment: Please explain the rules.  Why do you ignore `'S'` but treat `'I'` as a `'1'`?

Comment: I do not ignore the S. I've made a mistake I am sorry :(.

Comment: I've edited my post

Comment: Can you have any other characters in your inputs - ones that are not placeholders for digits? I understand that `'o'` was meant to mean zero; what if you have something like an `'h'` in the middle of a number? Do you want the conversion to number to fail, so that you have an opportunity to look at that particular number and decide how to handle it? (Or, better, to ask your users so THEY can decide how to handle?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the wonderful things about Oracle that some other DBs lack, is the TRANSLATE function:

```
SELECT TRANSLATE(number, 'SsIilOoxyz', '5511100') FROM t
```

This will convert:

```
S, s to 5
I, i and l to 1
O, o to 0
Remove any x, y or z from the number
```

The second and third arguments to translate define what characters are to be mapped. If the first string is longer than the second then anything over the length of the second is deleted from the resulting string. Mapping is direct based on position:

```
'SsIilOoxyz', 
'5511100'
```

Look at the columns of the characters; the character above is mapped to the character below:

```
S->5, 
s->5, 
I->1, 
i->1, 
l->1, 
O->0, 
o->0,
x->removed, 
y->removed, 
z->removed`
```

Comment: Thank you! It's totally the right answer.

Comment: @Dim433 another useful thing to use translate for: if you do `SELECT TRANSLATE(number, 'x1234567890', 'x') from t` then the results will be everything that is NOT a valid digit, because all the valid digits will be removed, leaving you just with results of all the invalid chars that are present in the column values, so you can design replacements for them

Comment: Postgres has a `translate()` function as well.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name mm.. SQLS too, but only since 2017 (about 20 years after Oracle!) and the strings must be the same length so not quite as useful..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `translate()` and along with `to_number()`.  Your rules are not exactly clear, but something like this:

```
select to_number(translate(price, '0123456789IoS', '012345678910'))
from t;
```

This replaces `I` with `1`, `o` with `0`, and removes `S`.

Comment: Thank you ! I'll try it and I'll let you know if it works

Comment: Your way is working! Thank you very much :). I'll also check over answers.

Comment: Why do you need to translate digits (to themselves)? That just wastes time for no real purpose. `translate()` should only translate non-digits to the proper digits.

Comment: I will accept @Caius Jard as the answer because it summarizes all the aspects of the function. But thank you for your reactivity :)

Comment: @mathguy indeed, about the only time you need to translate something to itself is if youre using TRANSLATE for remove-only; it's not acceptable to pass an empty string as the second arg so one has to pass a single dummy char that is translated to itself.. e.g. `TRANSLATE(.., ''remove', '') -> TRANSLATE(.., 'Xremove', 'X')`

Comment: @CaiusJard - that is not the only time. In this problem, suppose the OP wants to translate some letters and remove others (as in your example, but without knowing in advance what other characters - letters or otherwise - may be present). Then you could `translate(number, '01234567890SsIilOo' || number, '01234567895511100')`. This is why I asked the OP for clarification (in a comment below his original question).

Comment: Ye, that's reasonable, and something similar to the comment I just posted under my own answer..